# switch line class in clojurescript with if boolean variable

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

how can I switch the li class in a list with clojurescript, when the @switchvar is true all odd lines should be active, in the other case the even lines should be active

I tried an if statement, nothing happens.

```
(defn listitems [items]
  [:ul
   (for [item items]
     ^{:key item} [:li {:class 
        (if (@switchvar true) 
            ((odd? item) "active") 
            ((even? item) "active") ) 
      } "Item " item ])])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function that is within the `switchvar` atom, and giving it `true` as a parameter. Better to just deref (`@`) it:

```
(defn listitems [items]
  [:ul
   (for [item items
         idx (range (count items))]
     ^{:key item} [:li {:class
                        (if (and (odd? idx) (odd? @switchvar))
                          "active"
                          "inactive")
                        } "Item " item])])
```

I made a change so that there's an idx that will vary with each list item. So both `@switchvar` and `idx` can change. I hope you can alter this code to suit your exact needs.

Comment: ok, I understand a little bit more. but, I want to switch the even odd active thing when switchvar changes. In the line with "active"  I will do something like  ((odd? item) "active")  and in inactive ((even? item) "active")

Comment: I made a change to introduce `idx`. You should note that code like `((odd? item) "active")` does not make sense because `odd?` is a function that returns a boolean - and then your code invokes that boolean. And you can't invoke a boolean. You can invoke strange things like maps and keywords (where they act as functions), but you can't invoke a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement does not seem right. You could do something like that:

```
[:ul (map #(-> [:li {:class %2} "item" %1]) 
          items 
          (cycle ["active" "non-active"]))]
```

Comment: this switch the odd and even li elements, I want to change the active and not active class

Comment: ok, I try to understand. where is the problem with my for loop an the if statement?

Comment: just missing the @switchvar, I want to change the order or the active non-active class

Answer (score 0):

thanks@all, I got a good start into clojure with your hints. switchvar is actually boolean. I changed the first "inactive" to another if clause.

```
(defn lister-items2 [items]
  [:ul
   (for [item items ]
     ^{:key item} [:li {:class
                    (if (and (odd? item) (true? @switchvar))
                      "active"
                      (if (and (even? item) (false? @switchvar))
                        "active"
                        "inactive"))
                    } "Item " item])])
```